# Responsive Design with fixed width items

Tags: jquery, media-queries, fluid-layout, responsive-design

I am designing a layout similar to Comcast's listing page: http://xfinitytv.comcast.net/movies

If you resize your window, you will notice that there is often a blank space to the right when there isn't enough room for another poster to be there. I want to create a layout where there are always a perfect fit of posters (no space to the right).

The problem is that I cannot apply percentage-based widths to the posters, they stay at a fixed width of 180px. My theory was to use percentage based margins and media queries, but then there are the following setbacks: 1) poster art is not sticky to the right always 2) I must use far too many media queries. It just didnt feel right.

Ideally, it would work like this: If the screen size is in between x and x, then there are 8 posters in a row. If the screen size is between x and x, there are 7 posters in a row....so on and so forth. And all the space in between the poster are would be evenly distributed amongst the margins. This way, we use a media query-esque solution to display x number of poster art, and jquery to calculate and distribute margins. There will always be a nice fit of posters, always ending at the right-most part of the screen.

Any idea on a good way to go about this? It must work when the browser window is resized (not just on page load).

Comment: The solution is Soh Tankah's Smart Columns, but her site is down. I need the jquery code to test it out!

Comment: got it, no need for an answer

Comment: then post your answer and select the question as accepted

Answer (score 2):

This can indeed be implemented using CSS3 media selectors.

Lets say one coloumns has a width of 100 px, you have a sidebar with a width of 150 px, and the elements is wrapped inside a wrapper.

*Ideally, this should be implemented using LESS CSS or similar.*

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="sidebar">SIDEBAR</div>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="coloumn">ITEM</div>
        <div class="coloumn">ITEM</div>
        <div class="coloumn">ITEM</div>
        <div class="coloumn">ITEM</div>
        <div class="coloumn">ITEM</div>
        <div class="coloumn">ITEM</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
/*Default layout with 2 coloumns (150 + 2*100)*/
#sidebar
{
float:left;
width:150px;
}

#container
{
width:350px;
}

/*Coloumns outer width must be 100px*/
.coloumn
{
width:90px;
border:1px solid #000; /*Left + right = 2px*/
margin-left:8px;
background:#ccc;
display:inline;
}

#wrapper
{
margin-left:150px;
width:200px;
}

/*3 coloumns (150 + 3*100)*/
@media (min-width: 450px){
#wrapper
{
    width:300px;
}

#container
{
width:550px
}
}

/*4 coloumns (150 + 4*100)*/
@media (min-width: 550px){
#wrapper
{
    width:400px;
}

#container
{
width:550px
}
}
```